# snowflake stored procedure to update a column in a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have three snowflake tables. Table 'TEST' and 'TEST1' has 3 columns. I want to insert data from TEST to TEST1 for columns specified in 'KEY_COLUMNS' column of 'CONTROL' table. For example  I have id,name in 'KEY_COLUMNS' column of 'CONTROL' table. So I need to intert column id,name from TEST to TEST1.

TEST TABLE

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  id varchar(100), 
  name varchar(100),
  COL VARCHAR(64)
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values (100, 'ABC', null);
INSERT INTO TEST values (200, 'XYZ', null);
```

My control table looks like below

```
create OR REPLACE table CONTROL_TABLE (
  KEY_COLUMNS VARCHAR,
  COL1 VARCHAR,
  COL2 VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO CONTROL_TABLE values ('id,name', null, null);
```

I have created a stored procedure as below which actually takes care of the above logic
Now, I want to have another query to update NEW column in TEST1 as 'XXXX'. I did try the below query but it fails at query2. QUERY 1 runs completely fine. What is wrong with query2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST() 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$  
    DECLARE
           source_tbl STRING := 'TEST';
           hash_columns STRING;
           query1 STRING;
           query2 STRING;
     BEGIN

          SELECT KEY_COLUMNS INTO :hash_columns FROM DEV_COMMON_DATA.RAW_OD_CMS.CONTROL_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME = :source_tbl;
          
          QUERY1 := 'insert into TEST1
                            ('|| :hash_columns ||')
                          select '|| :hash_columns ||' from TEST;';
                          
          QUERY2 := 'update TEST1 set HASH_KEY = 'XXXX';';


           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY1;
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY2;

           RETURN :QUERY1;
           RETURN :QUERY2;
      END;
      $$;
    
 call TEST();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see there are some missing (structure of TEST1) and incorrect information (missing columns in CONTROL_TABLE). So I created the TEST1 and CONTROL_TABLE like this:

```
create OR REPLACE table CONTROL_TABLE (
  KEY_COLUMNS VARCHAR,
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO CONTROL_TABLE values ('id,name', 'TEST');

create OR REPLACE table TEST1 (
  id varchar(100), 
  name varchar(100),
  HASH_KEY VARCHAR(64)
);
```

And also fixed some issues with commas in the SP (it might be related to copy/paste:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST() 
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$  
DECLARE
   source_tbl STRING := 'TEST';
   hash_columns STRING;
   query1 STRING;
   query2 STRING;
BEGIN

  SELECT KEY_COLUMNS INTO :hash_columns FROM CONTROL_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME = :source_tbl;

  QUERY1 := 'insert into TEST1 ('|| :hash_columns ||')
                  select '|| :hash_columns ||' from TEST';

  QUERY2 := 'update TEST1 set HASH_KEY = ''XXXX''';


   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY1;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY2;


   RETURN :QUERY1;
END;
$$;
```

When I call the SP, I see that everything is OK:

```
call TEST();
 
select * from test1;

+-----+------+----------+
| ID  | NAME | HASH_KEY |
+-----+------+----------+
| 100 | ABC  | XXXX     |
| 200 | XYZ  | XXXX     |
+-----+------+----------+
```

But I couldn't be sure if this is the right approach. Why do you want to run "update TEST1 set HASH_KEY = 'XXXX'" and update all rows with same HASH_KEY?

Something like this makes more sense (to me):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST() 
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$  
DECLARE
   source_tbl STRING := 'TEST';
   hash_columns STRING;
   query1 STRING;
   query2 STRING;
BEGIN

  SELECT KEY_COLUMNS INTO :hash_columns FROM CONTROL_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME = :source_tbl;

  QUERY1 := 'insert into TEST1 ('|| :hash_columns ||' , HASH_KEY )
                  select '|| :hash_columns ||' , HASH( ' || :hash_columns  || ' ) from TEST';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY1;

  RETURN :QUERY1;
END;
$$;
```